# Using a number as an input won't work properly

Tags: input

My code is

```py
a=input()
if input == ("999"):
    print("It works.")
else:
    print("No, it doesn't")
```

and I input "999" it will always come out with "No, it doesn't". what do I do?

Comment: What language is this though?

Comment: sorry im not sure how formatting on this site works yet but it is all correct in python 3.6

Comment: @Phiter it's Python 3.6

Comment: Try removing the parenthesis.
if a == "999"

Answer (score 0):

You're checking if `input` equals `"999"`, but input is the function you call and it won't hold the value. You should compare the variable value instead.

```py
a = input()
if a == ("999"):
  print("It works.")
else:
  print("No, it doesn't")
```

Comment: Oh that was me being an idiot with the test. I've just fixed it but it still does the same thing.

Comment: Not supposed to happen. Check this repl https://repl.it/repls/ExtrasmallAssuredMining#main.py